# Replace numbers from a docx string in Python

Tags: python, python-docx

So I've been playing for a while with docx-python and couldn't figure out a way to replace the numbers from a string.
I have a paragraph that is like this: NR 050 / 04.10.2019
I did manage to get the numbers separate, put them in a list and modify them as I will. How do I put back in the paragraph from the docx file the modified values?
Here's my code so far:

```py
document = Document('1.docx')

section = document.sections[0]
header = section.header
order = []
for paragraph in header.paragraphs:
    print(paragraph.text)

    for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', paragraph.text):
        int(s)
        order.append(int(s))

print('Contract number:',order[0],'\nContract Date: ',order[1],order[2],order[3])
order[0] = order[0] + 1
print('New contract number: ',order[0])


today = date.today()
day = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
data_curenta = []
for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', day):
    int(s)
    data_curenta.append(int(s))

print('Current date: ',data_curenta[0],data_curenta[1],data_curenta[2])

order[1] = data_curenta[0]
order[2] = data_curenta[1]
order[3] = data_curenta[2]
print('New contract date: ',order[1],order[2],order[3])
```

Comment: Please show some example input and output (see: [mcve]). As far as I can tell, this question has nothing to do with docx-python.

Comment: I already have the needed values, my question is: How do I put back in the docx paragraph the numbers that I have? I couldn't find a replace or search function in docx-python documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simple way to convert a string to number is to convert it to int, if the number is a float try this

```
 num=" 44.545"
 print(int(float(num)))
```

output

```
44
```

to separate string in list use split : your_text_var.split("eg. your seprator")

```
 txt="123.45.67"
 newvar= txt.split(".")
print(newvar)
```

output

```
['123', '45', '67']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But my question is how do I replace the text in docx file. How do I select a certain paragraph and modify it?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24813382/8436879

Comment: This answer doesn’t address the question by @Sup6, except in that link which proves it’s a duplicate...?