# Python how to replace a word with a hyperlink in MS Word using docx?

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I want to replace a word in my paragraph with a hyperlink. I saw functions that can create a new word with hyperlink but that's not what I want. For example I want to do something like this:

```
mydoc = docx.Document()
text = "a stackoverflow question"
parag = mydoc.add_paragraph(text)
parag.add_hyperlink(the word that will be changed to the hyperlink (in that case
                    that can be "stackoverflow"), link('https://stackoverflow.com'))
```

With this `add_hyperlink` function, the **stackoverflow** word must be a hyperlink.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can follow the solution proposed by @scanny [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805671/how-to-use-python-docx-to-replace-text-in-a-word-document-and-save)!

Comment: It didn't work, it needs string but mine is hyperlink so I got this error `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not CT_R`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build up the paragraph run by run, something like:

```
document = docx.Document()
paragraph = mydoc.add_paragraph()
paragraph.add_run("a ")
paragraph.add_hyperlink("stackoverflow", link('https://stackoverflow.com'))
paragraph.add_run("question")
```

A hyperlink must appear as its own run, so you need a separate run before and after if you want to put it in the middle of a sentence.

Comment: This worked but kinda different. After I add this, when I run my script, it starts overwriting to the old file everytime I restart the program. Then I deleted these lines but problem is still continue. I'm confused, I litterally change nothing except the code that you write.

Comment: Even in that code, it's overwriting the old file. This wasn't happening before I don't know what happend. Do you have any idea?
`import docx`

`myfile = docx.Document()`

`parag = myfile.add_paragraph('test')`

`myfile.save('myfile.docx')`