# Index Word Documents to Search Fast Python

Tags: python-3.x, search, indexing

I Have a Folder of Many .docx Files

[Folder of Word Documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pWCX.png)

and each .docx file contains many medical terms.

I Want To index all of them to search faster.

for Example:-

I Have a Folder named examplefolder

I have a 100 Word Document Files with .docx extension

Each File contains 1000 + Words

I Want To Search a Word Across all the 100 Files !!

Is There a python Code to Do Like That ?

Comment: the ```python-docx``` module might help, have a look: https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/ (how to download), https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (documentation = how to use it)

Comment: I Think I Cannot Index the Word Files to Search Fast if  I use this Library

Comment: well i guess its gonna take a long time anyway to search these files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805671/how-to-use-python-docx-to-replace-text-in-a-word-document-and-save if you still plan to use the library the accepted answer in the link above could help coding a search function for the document.

Comment: It is For Find and Replace. I Want to search a tern if it exists in any word document in folder. and in single folder there are thousands of word files

Comment: you can just use the find function for finding the word. also there are functions from the module ```os``` which allow you to see all the files in a folder

Comment: it is taking so much time if i am using the os find. instead i want a program that indexes all the words in the word document ad makes my search faster

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the terminal by using [Antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) to convert the doc files into a grep-able format and then grep on its output-

```
antiword *.docx | grep "your-medical-term"
```

Comment: There are Thousands of Medical Terms in a single Word document. I cannot do it 1 by 1. I Want To Index every Word which is separated be spaces.

Comment: I Heard of csv in python. If we can index all words seperated by commas, then we can find any word from that word.

Comment: And By The Way, I am Not That Handy with the Terminal

Comment: Can you show me a sample of what you're trying to accomplish? I'll write/suggest a pythonic(or something which doesn't involves terminal) solution based on that.

Comment: ok. I am trying to accomplish a faster search results of a word from a word Document