# Replace string in word document Python docx

Tags: python, cpu-word, txt

I need to replace a string in a word document with keeping the formatting of a word document. Trying to do with "Docx", however getting errors.

Thanks ain advance for your assistance

Comment: According to the help page, that package is a _A pure python-based utility to extract text and images from docx files._ It doesn't say anything about saving. [How to use python-docx to replace text in a Word document and save](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24813382)

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe interested in python-docx. You are able to create Word files from Python, so it might fit your needs. Check [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#python-docx).

Comment: Thank you for response. Edited my question based on that. Now trying to figure out with docx.